# Performance consideration for updating 100 records

Tags: performance, entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4.3

I am developing an application which has a SCQL CE 4.0 database and I used EF 4.3.1 as its ORM.
There's a requirement that I have to load 100 records from an XML file check them against the database (By their GUID column) and if they are new, inserting them but if some of them already exist I have to update those records.

Now I'm wondering what is the best approach to this requirement?

For now I'm using the following code but I don't think it's efficient.

```
foreach( var record in xmlRecords )
{
    var existingRecord = context.Records.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Guid == record.Guid);
    if( existingRecord == null )
        context.Records.Add(record);
    else
        context.Records.ApplyCurrentValues(record);
 }

 context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: i don't know this framework but I think that the only good advice - when dealing with SQL or external databases - is to just use their own functions, don't shape your business logic in C or C++ or whatever language you are using, just search for the appropriate function in the SQL docs and only use those functions and let them do the work for you.

Comment: i disagree with user1824407 entirely... I think you are on the right track of keeping your business logic in your application not in your data layer.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine, other is to have Stored Procedure taking XML as input and then writing insert and update command using the XML but SQL CE does not support XML data types

Answer (score 0):

> For now I'm using the following code but I don't think it's efficient.

Sounds like what you have works.  Have you done a test run with processing 100 records?  Is there some reason that you want to optimize this more?  If your code can reasonably handle processing 100 records ( i would imagine reasonable in this case being less than a second or two) and that's your requirement then you are done.  Entity framework, and I would imagine all other ORM's can easily handle updating 100 rows.  If you are worried that you will need to handle more records in the future then create a big test file with appropriate number of records and see how it performs.  Optimize from there.

If it anit broke don't fix it.  Don't optimize until your code can't handle the load.  Your users aren't going to be able to tell the difference between 1.1 seconds and 1.1222 seconds.

If you do have to optimize something I would throw your assumptions about whats running slow out the window.  It's almost never what you expect.  Throw some timer statements in your code to see what slowing you down.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Its not totally about customers satisfaction but for the sake of better programming.

Comment: Your code looks pretty clean to me.  Better programming is more about does it work (i.e. does it meet user requirements), and can you maintain it.  Optimization often makes your code more complex, i.e. harder to maintain.  Don't do it unless you have a reason.  If your code was hard to understand, or if it was running slow then I would say refactor/optimize.  Otherwise I'd leave it be.  Additionally you could be spending your time on other tasks that have a bigger impact that this optimization would.  Good luck